# Remote connection is intermittent

Tags: apache, connection, debian, mariadb

I have a problem with my MariaDB server.

Server A Debian: MariaDB + apache2.

Server B Debian: apache2 + Remote access to MariaDB  from (A) server.

The problem is that server B often is losing connections with MariaDB.
Sometimes connection is okey but sometimes it shows error: "Server has gone away".

On server A apache work with MariaBD via localhost and everything works fine.

I thought it might be iptables problem.

```
root@xxx:/home/x# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --
```

Also here is my.cnf file:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
external-locking
delay-key-write=OFF
query-cache-size=0
skip-name-resolve
default-storage-engine=INNODB
    character-set-server=utf8
    collation-server=utf8_bin

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 195....
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 10000
table_cache            = 128
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 10M
query_cache_size        = 160M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#slow_query_log      = 1
#long_query_time = 2
#log_queries_not_using_indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

I have no idea how can i resolve this problem...
I also tested connection to MariaDB from other servers but they also were losing connections.
i did also everything what was written here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Nothing helped.
Thanks.

Comment: Is client or server at home? In such case, consider that the router could be the problem (cheap router provided by ISP). Why do you check the state of the connection if you will accept it anyway?

Comment: BTW are you sure about `max_connections`? 10000 seems way to much. 100 should be enough.

Comment: Both are dedicated servers bought at the oneprovider.com

Comment: Well i was trying to change some settings, cause i had no idea why it didnt work

Comment: Ok, so the routers should be OK, also with 10000 connections (which it is in any case bad. You should "cache" connection on apache site,

Comment: Does it change anything?

Comment: you can have maximal 65000 connection (ports), before to do reuse a connection there is also some wait period. (both IPs and destination port are the same, so it is just the port that limits connections). But now I don't remember if there are limits on iptables and kernel (with standard settings), so I would also change iptable to be stateless (in any case you accept NEW and ESTABLISHED)

Comment: I did:

iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -j NOTRACK
iptables -t raw -I OUTPUT -j NOTRACK

But with no effect

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be, that every request generates a new connection to the database server. Since it can just handle a defined amount of connections, it will not allow anymore connections and this will result in the error shown above.

Use a (micro)service on the Apache server that handles the Apache requests and has one ore more permanent connections to the database.

Apache -> Service -> _permanent_connection_ -> Database

Comment: Thanks for answer.

So You mean that i suppose to user Persistent Connections right?

Comment: Persistent connections only make sense, if both ends of the process exist persistently. Your connection presumably gets renewed on every HTTP request.  That's why you need the service (daemon) in between. The persistent connection may help for multiple database accesses during one request.

Comment: Im not sure how can i make this deamon.
Could You send me links for page where i can read about it?
Thanks